# When is JavaScript superior to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Taking a look at jQuery for the first time yesterday, it looks amazing. I've been fiddling with some easy jQuery tutorials back and forth, and some questions come to mind.

Can JavaScript achieve something jQuery can't? Can JavaScript achieve something in a simpler, faster way than jQuery? Or is it so that jQuery is simply just overall better?

So the basic question here is: Is JavaScript ever 'better' to use than jQuery?

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Comment: I know, but are there some situations where the better option is to use 'pure' javascript, and not rely on the jquery library? Does using jquery have certain drawbacks in opposite to using 'normal' JS?

Comment: It all depends on the context.  Are you referring to performance? efficiency? ease of maintenance? robustness against future updates to JavaScript?  There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this kind of question.  The simplest answer is, use whichever one you understand or like better, and when you have a problem, deal with the problem then.

Comment: I was referring more to the difference between javascript and jquery as a programmer; whats more efficient, what does more with less etc. I do understand this is a very wide question (and therefore hard to answer), but I want to get the wider opinion of jquery and its uses versus javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is a javascript library, so there is nothing you can do with jQuery that you cannot with javascript.

JQuert provides an API that is:

- Crossbrowser.
- More convenient that the DOM API in many ways.

But: since it's a wrapper, you might in some cases have a better performance using native APIs.

However, don't be fooled: unless you stumble upon a very specific case where performance is a key point, the time you will spare by using jQuery API will often let you more time to write cleaner, more robust, more efficient code, and in the end compensate the microscopic overhead of jQuery in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does create a certain level of overhead that is not there in raw/pure javascript. So many times jQuery can be overkill. Instead of just assuming jQuery is better (I both love and use it myself) ask yourself on each project, does jQuery add functionality that I need and cannot accomplish easily with javascript? If the answer is yes, use it. If not, don't use it. It's just a tool, not a replacement for the language itself.

Finally, as was commented. jQuery is JavaScript. Plain and simple.